# FullCalendar V2 Styling

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I just installed the new version of FullCalendar and one thing that is bothering me is that the title doesn't show entirely it cuts instead of breaking to the next line like the previous version did.

How can I change it to break the line when the title is too long instead of cutting it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow-wrap : break-word;` comes to mind, paired with an explicit width like `width : 50%;`

It would help to see some relevant code.

EDIT: after seeing fiddle, you can add

```
.fc-day-grid-event > .fc-content {
    white-space: inherit;
}
```

Make sure the selector is qualified enough to override the default styling, and to always avoid using !important.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Is that on .fc-event or .fc-view-container? Thanks again!

Comment: Whichever div containing the title you are talking about.  Having a link, photo, codepen, jsFiddle or anything to understand the context of your question is going to help a lot.

Comment: Hi, I created the Fiddle with a standard example from FullCalendar. If you see there are two events cutting the title off (http://jsfiddle.net/kitarafrei/uawsdebv/)